# Auto-close tmux pane when its stdin is closed

Tags: pipe, tmux

I made a program where I use the classic pipe-fork-exec to have a pipe connected to a process running `tmux split-window -dI`, so when I write to that pipe, the newly created pane print what's written.

I would like to have that pane automatically close when the pipe is closed. Are there flags I can give to tmux to achieve this, or is there an alternative way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Can you precise how you call your program within tmux? Default tmux config is to close the window when the command completes (option `remain-on-exit` controls the behavior). Maybe you should call your program within the `split-window -dI` command itself?

Comment: @kaliko no, the program already run at this point, and I just want a pipe that write to a tmux pane. A thread use this pipe to write its output while the original pane runs a REPL.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to have an empty pane closed when the process piping to it closes its stdout. You need to kill the pane yourself with `kill-pane`.

Comment: Sounds like a next feature request!